# regexp_substr not working when value changing

Tags: sql, oracle

I want the min and max marks for each student. Below are the sample marks, 
I want the uc_min as whatever coming before / and uc_max as whatever coming as after /

Below is my code, It is not working for single digit

```sql
select distinct  regexp_substr(marks,'[^/]+',1,1) uc_min, 
        regexp_substr(marks,'[^/]+',4,1)  uc_max
   from std
  where student_id = 'YYY'
```

Expected output:

```
Sample marks   Expected uc_min    Expected uc_max
1/100          1                  100
20/30          20                 30
180/730        180                730
20/200         20                 200
```

Answer (score 0):

A `substr/ instr` solution, assuming that there's a single `"/"`

```
select substr(marks, 1, instr(marks,'/') - 1) as uc_min,
       substr(marks, instr(marks,'/') + 1) as uc_max
from std;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=050fb7c0741ca9c125b48ac8016e3333)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH MARKS (SAMPLE_MARKS) AS 
(SELECT '1/100' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20/30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '180/730' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20/200' FROM DUAL)
SELECT DISTINCT
    SAMPLE_MARKS,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(SAMPLE_MARKS, '[^/]+', 1, 1) UC_MIN,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(SAMPLE_MARKS, '[^/]+', 1, 2) UC_MAX -- start point(1) and position(2) was incorrect in your code 
FROM
    MARKS
```

[image]

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83a750b409efebccce5f7a5fe4c96fa1)

Cheers!!